# Join two tables and and have the name as a column, and the second table as row

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

Having as always a very hard time to join tables...

I have two tables, the first one is `stocks`.

```
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+
| id |    name    | symbol |  ticker  | currency |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Swedban    | swedb  | swedb.st | sek      |
|  2 | ABB        | abb    | abb.st   | sek      |
|  3 | Alfa Laval | alfa   | alfa.st  | sek      |
+----+------------+--------+----------+----------+
```

And the second one is `prices`

```
+----+----------+---------------------+------+-----+------+-------+-----------+--------+------------+
| id | stock_id |        ydate        | open | low | high | close | adj_close | volume | created_at |
+----+----------+---------------------+------+-----+------+-------+-----------+--------+------------+
|  1 |        1 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |  115 | 110 |  116 |   116 |       116 |    354 | 2021-01-03 |
|  2 |        2 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |   12 |  13 |   13 |    12 |        12 |    345 | 2021-01-03 |
|  3 |        3 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |   44 |  45 |   45 |    45 |        45 |  46456 | 2021-01-03 |
|  4 |        1 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |  110 | 111 |  111 |   111 |       111 | 678678 | 2021-01-03 |
|  5 |        2 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |   11 |  15 |   13 |    13 |        13 |  12313 | 2021-01-03 |
|  6 |        3 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |   40 |  44 |   43 |    43 |        43 |  13412 | 2021-01-03 |
|  7 |        1 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |  109 | 120 |  119 |   119 |       119 |    464 | 2021-01-03 |
|  8 |        2 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |   15 |  16 |   16 |    16 |        16 | 234243 | 2021-01-03 |
|  9 |        3 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |   43 |  43 |   43 |    43 |        43 |   1234 | 2021-01-03 |
+----+----------+---------------------+------+-----+------+-------+-----------+--------+------------+
```

The expected result should be:

```
+---+---------------------+---------+-----+------------+
|   |        ydate        | Swedban | ABB | Alfa Lavel |
+---+---------------------+---------+-----+------------+
| 1 | 2020-01-02 00:00:00 |     116 |  12 |         45 |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 00:00:00 |     111 |  13 |         43 |
| 3 | 2020-01-04 00:00:00 |     119 |  16 |         43 |
+---+---------------------+---------+-----+------------+
```

So stock names should be columns. And the `adj_close` and `ydate` rows.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?  in SQL you could use piviot tables, not sure of syntax in MySQL but you can look into that and post some code examples once you get them and we can help more.

Comment: you need to use pivot and most probably dynamic sql to get the list of company names

Comment: This operation is called pivoting and has been asked and answerered here on SO sooooo many times! The duplicate question shows how to perform a pivot with a dynamic number of columns using mysql only. However, pls note that it may be a lot more efficient to perform such a transformation in the application code rather than in mysql!